# Why couldn't I clear an input?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<input type="text" class="input">
```

It must be cleared. jQuery:

```
$(".input").text("")
```

It doesn't work. But this `$(".input").val("")` worked. Why?
And why couldn't I assign value in `input` in this manner `$(".input").text("")`?

Comment: Because `input`s have no texts, but values. Period.

Comment: I think you could have googled for your answer. This isn't really a problem with programming, this is clearly a lack of research.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might help to remember that $('input').val() gives you the text that a user can edit, but $('p').text() gives you the text that the user cannot edit. So when you set $('input').val('Something'), it will display "Something" in the form field, but the user might change it to be "Something Else". If you set $('p').text("Something"), though, then the user cannot change it.

Comment: Point that making $(".input") you are selecting all DOM elements with the class input, but your input doesn't have that class